# How to add Google Font to Rails Asset pipeline icw Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Rails with bootstrap, but I have no clue how to add a custom font. The problem is this:

- When I add the @import in my application.css.scss, it's loaded after
  the custom.css.scss, so the font is not respected.
- When I add it at the top of custom.css.scss, the normalize.css from bootstrap comes after it, so it gets resetted.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?